# Camel JMS with CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode not working

Tags: jms, apache-camel, spring-jms

I am unable to acknowledge JMS message with CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE mode in camel. After digging a into the stack trace I found that ***message.acknowledge()*** in ***AbstractMessageListenerContainer*** 
is always being executed which causes the auto-ack behavior. Am I configured anything wrong?

**org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.commitIfNecessary(Session, Message)**

```
protected void commitIfNecessary(Session session, Message message) throws JMSException {
        // Commit session or acknowledge message.
        if (session.getTransacted()) {
            // Commit necessary - but avoid commit call within a JTA transaction.
            if (isSessionLocallyTransacted(session)) {
                // Transacted session created by this container -> commit.
                JmsUtils.commitIfNecessary(session);
            }
        }
        else if (message != null && isClientAcknowledge(session)) {
            message.acknowledge();
        }
    }
```

**Spring Configuration**

```
<bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachedConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="asyncConsumer" value="true" />
    <property name="acknowledgementModeName" value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE" />
</bean>

<bean id="cachedConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="30" />
</bean>
```

**Camel Route**

```
from(jmsTerminalRequest).routeId("generic-jms-inbound").setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly).threads(5, 20, "generic-jms-inbound").bean(clientAckProcessor).to("...")
```

Comment: What is the problem? camel-jms uses spring which has that auto ack functionality.

Comment: The problem is on the client ack. If the client ack is done before creating the threads, it works fine. i.e.  from(jmsTerminalRequest).routeId("generic-jms-inbound").setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly).bean(clientAckProcessor).threads(5, 20, "generic-jms-inbound").to("...")

Comment: Use concurrentConsumers=5&maxConcurrentConsumers=20 on the from JMX endpoint instead of threads(5,20) and it should work

Comment: Thanks. However, the vendor only provides JMS1.x spec which doesn't support maxConcurrentConsumers option. No matter what you set, it just run in single thread.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is specifying acknowledgement mode within route consuming endpoint definition:

```
from("...?maxConcurrentConsumers=20&acknowledgementModeName=CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE")
    .bean(clientAckProcessor)
    .to("...")
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I will have to try out in our scenario but this advanced option is officially documented [here](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html).